# How would a planet react to a sudden weakening of its sun?

Tags: magic, science-fiction

So I'm writing a novel, where the planet's sun is (although the people who live on the planet don't know this) artificial. It requires a "sacrifice" of blood magic that fuels its core once every 20-30 years, but for plot reasons, things don't go according to plan and it doesn't get its blood. 
How would a planet react to such a phenomena? It loses about half of its "strength" and it will go on for a year or so, before completely snuffing out.

The planet is like a remnant of old technology. It's actually a terraformed moon, with an artificial sun that is collapsing. It was set to receive "magic blood" to reignite itself after some decades, but it's getting more and more unstable. The civilizations on the planet believe that it's just "magic", as they live in a sort of medieval era since the Sun construction took place millennia ago "By the gods."

My main question would be how would it affect the light available, and also warmth? Would the flora and fauna start to die immediately? Sorry for the vagueness, too, english isn't my main language.

Comment: This needs a bit more context. Do the people have the technology to perform measurements to the sun like we in our current era have or not?

Comment: The planet is like a remnant of old tecnology. Its actually a terraformed moon, with an artificial sun that is colapsing. It was set to receive "magic blood" to reignite itself after some decades, but its getting more and more unstable. The civilizations on the planet believe that its just "magic", as they live in a sort of medieval era, since the suns construction took place millenia ago "By the gods."

Comment: @MarlonNascimento, you should put this information in your question using the [edit] button.

Comment: You also may want to narrow this question down a little.  Asking what the effects on the whole planet would be is very broad, and in its current state, this question is most likely going to get closed.  Narrowing the question down to one specific aspect of the planet will help a lot.

Comment: Sorry, first time user. My main question would be how would it affect the light avaliable, and also warmth? Would the flora and fauna start to die imediately? Sorry for the vagueness, too, english isnt my main language.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Marlon*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: I don’t think planets “react”. They passively endure whatever happens around them.

Comment: See answers to thisb https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/59051 and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2629

Comment: As you have more than 5 reputation and can now post on [Meta] I want to inform you about our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions). There you can test a question to get feedback on the general stuff such as on-topic/off-topic, grammar, typos, possible duplicates, missing information, etc. before releasing the question onto the Main Site. Just a tip in case you want to give it a try with future questions. Have fun!